# MYSQL Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value while updating

Tags: mysql, double, truncated

Here is request for mysql database.
    `"UPDATE client_storrage SET LastMatched=UTC_TIMESTAMP() WHERE XUID=01100000000000"`
It gives error Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '01100000000000'
XUID            varchar(20) utf8_bin
LastMatched datetime
Can any one help to fix this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if XUID is a `varchar` you have to use quotes around it in your query:

```
UPDATE client_storrage 
SET LastMatched = UTC_TIMESTAMP() 
WHERE XUID = '01100000000000'
```